# ComboBoxes que compartilham o mesmo DataSource, trocam a seleção juntos

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Estou fazendo um projeto de ordem de produção e tenho 7 combobox pegando os valores da mesma tabela (que sao as de materias primas). Estou usando esse código no `load` do formulario para carregar as combobox:

```
cmbMP1.DataSource = bllprodutos.DtMateriaPrima;
cmbMP1.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
cmbMP1.ValueMember = "ID";
cmbMP1.Refresh();

cmbMP2.DataSource = bllprodutos.DtMateriaPrima;
cmbMP2.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
cmbMP2.ValueMember = "ID";
cmbMP2.Refresh();
//.......
```

Até ai tudo bem, quando o formulário carrega monta a lista dos ComboBox, mas ai vem a dor de cabeça. Quando eu seleciono qualquer valor de qualquer uma delas todas as outras ComboBox ficam com o mesmo valor, tipo não consigo selecionar produtos diferentes entre elas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que o `ComboBox` acaba criando (mesmo sem a real intenção do programador)  um mesmo `BindingContext` para os dois `ComboBoxes`, já que você está usando o mesmo objeto como `DataSource`.

Para se livrar deste comportamento, você precisa declarar um novo `BindingContext` para todos os `ComboBoxes` que irão utilizar este objeto.

```
// resto do código
cmbMP2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
cmbMP2.DataSource = bllprodutos.DtMateriaPrima;
//resto do código
```

Comment: opaaaa Jbueno... testei aqui e deu certinhoo... vlw msm cara obrigado o/

Comment: Sempre à disposição.